# How to find top states with the largest count of positive cases on a specific date, in RStudio?

Tags: r, statistics

How to find top states with the largest count of positive cases on a specific date?

I am using RStudio and I am struggling to find the code to find the answer to my question. Below is an example of my dataset.

dput:

```
structure(list(date = c(20200402, 20200403, 20200327, 20200407, 
20200408, 20200403, 20200407, 20200407), state = c("MA", "IL", 
"NJ", "GA", "WA", "PA", "WA", "TX"), positive = c(8966, 8904, 
8825, 8818, 8682, 8420, 8384, 8262)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?

Comment: I tried using the suggested code below, but I am still struggling to find the code. The best code function df and dplyr. However the function won't show me the exact pinpoint of the dates with highest amount of cases, under a certain circumstance (i.e. date).

Answer (score 0):

Using your data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(20200402, 20200403, 20200327, 20200407, 
20200408, 20200403, 20200407, 20200407), state = c("MA", "IL", 
"NJ", "GA", "WA", "PA", "WA", "TX"), positive = c(8966, 8904, 
8825, 8818, 8682, 8420, 8384, 8262)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(max = max(positive))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(date), .(Max = max(positive)), date]
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(date = c(20200402, 20200403, 20200327, 20200407, 
20200408, 20200403, 20200407, 20200407), state = c("MA", "IL", 
"NJ", "GA", "WA", "PA", "WA", "TX"), positive = c(8966, 8904, 
8825, 8818, 8682, 8420, 8384, 8262)), row.names = c(NA, -8L),
class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```